# Only armv7 no armv6 option

Tags: iphone, ios

So I am trying to build my app for iPhone 3.0 and greater so I can get the largest range of users. It says that I need Architecture armv6. When I go to the architectures it only gives me the option for Standard armv7.

How am I supposed to get armv6 on there so that my app can be supported. Is this something in xcode 4.2 they are using to try and force developers to developer more toward 4.3 and greater?

I know there are other questions like this. I haven't found any that help yet though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding armv6 manually to the list of architectures to build. Even if it isn't in the dropdown menu, double click it and you will get a dropdown list in which you can add any architecture you like.

Also make sure you add armv6 to the list of Valid Architectures.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I double click it and all that happens is it opens the drop down with only arcv7 there. There are no other options. If you click others... it opens a screen with just the one option as well. I don't see armv6 anywhere. I'm under the Project's Build Settings

Comment: After you click others you should have a plus icon which you can click to add another architecture, or just click an empty line to start editing it.

Comment: Ok so as soon as I click it it opens up the other box. I click the plus sign. And it adds a line that is ready to edit. It wouldn't work if I just typed in armv6 correct?

Comment: Well I typed it in and it may have worked. Although, do I need armv7 on my application too? Cause as soon as armv6 was made and I set it to it it took over all the slots

Comment: You can have both armv6 and armv7 in your custom list. Again make sure you set both armv6 and armv7 in the "Architectures to Build" and in the "Valid Architectures".